# The type 'IdentityUser' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity

I'm badly stuck here.[image: t]
I'm getting this error
**Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0012  The type 'IdentityUser' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.   EmployeeManagement.DataAccess   E:\Toseef Ahmad\Learning\ASP.NET CORE Application\EmployeeManagement\EmployeeManagement.DataAccess\AppDbContext.cs  7   Active**

When I Install package Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores Version=2.2.0.0 from nuget package manager
then package is installed. but the error still persist there. Am i missing something !

Answer (score 0):

ok my bad,
      I'm installing Package(Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores) in main project. but Should've to intall this package in DataAccess project. like this, after selecting DataAccess project in package manager console.

> Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores -version 2.2.0